# What is the quickest way to find the asp.net file location of an html element in UI?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, web-applications, user-interface

Let's imagine you have an asp.net page in front of you full of input elements, user controls and panels etc. And you are asked to modify a specific textBox and you do not know where that textBox stands in your project.

Most of the time I use FireBug and try to see the Id of that element but it is not the best way all the time.

So,

What is the fastest way you believe that can be used to locate the source file that houses a specific html element in your web project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with your own suggestion and use Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I use IE's developer toolbar to hover over the element, grab the ID/Name and Ctrl+F in the page from VS. Depending on your project sometimes looking at the generated ID/Name you'll be able to tell if it's in a user control or not.